# show a specific number of letters from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a problem PHP/MySQL somebody help me to fix it plz
iam using this code to show a number of letters from a field in my database

```
$news_whole= $row_news['smalltext'];
  echo substr($news_whole,0,600);
```

but sometimes the result ..at the end there is like a square ..i don't know what is it.
how can i remove it!!!?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as a graphic. It makes it unsearchable for future users, and also makes it impossible for people trying to help you to copy and paste it to test. Please edit your post and add the code to the actual question; format it as code by clicking the `{}` button, indenting each line by 4 spaces, or by selecting all and pressing Ctrl+K. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a multi-byte character set and should use `mb_substr()` OR MySQL's own `SUBSTRING()` function in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

try use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) before of save data in database... and after use urldecode.

Answer (score 0):

Is the square an unprintable character?  Look at the output with a Hex editor and identify what ASCII value the square represents then identify where that values comes from - probably dirty data in my experience.